# Creating horizontal and vertical dotted lines in android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I want to draw horizontal and vertical dotted lines in android using shapes.

I want to draw like this

[image]

For Horizontal line

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="line" >

    <stroke
        android:dashGap="6px"
        android:dashWidth="6px"
        android:color="#C7B299" />

</shape>
```

For vertical line

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="line" >
<size
     android:height="400dp"/>
    <stroke
        android:dashGap="6px"
        android:dashWidth="6px"
        android:color="#C7B299" />

</shape>
```

But vertical dotted line not displaying my output shows like this

[image]

How to draw vertical line.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I found the solution

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="90"
    android:toDegrees="90" >

    <shape android:shape="line" >
        <stroke
            android:dashGap="6px"
            android:dashWidth="6px"
            android:color="#C7B299" />
    </shape>

</rotate>
```

OR

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="90"
    android:toDegrees="90"
    android:drawable="@drawable/horizontal_line"/>
```

Comment: I had to make a modification to make the vertical line to appear. I couldn't put the code in correct style here so I added new answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/34856660/5309676

Comment: This way to rotate is better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34856660/1935135

Comment: For vertical view, you have to give `match_parent` in width.

Comment: I had the same issue and the line was not visible. I 've just added the following code in my imageview and it worked

            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"

Comment: Custom component approach by user846316 and ulix will work for most android system as it follows official approach. I suggest reconsider right answer.

Answer (score 62):

If the View has 1dp width then just rotating your horizontal line is not enough. The vertical line’s length will be 1dp as it is drawn horizontally first, then rotated. Here is a trick to solve this problem:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:left="-300dp"
        android:right="-300dp">
        <rotate
            android:drawable="@drawable/dash_line_divider_horizontal"
            android:fromDegrees="90"
            android:toDegrees="90"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: If you want a vertical divider with dashed line, you can set this xml drawable as background of the view you use as divider.

Comment: @Sfseyhan can you explain why you set left and right to `-300dp` ?

Comment: @Sufian since the line is first drawn horizontally and then rotated, we need enough space horizontally to draw it. Using -300dp on both sides, you can draw 600dp horizontally and then it will be rotated. In my case 600dp is more then enough, but feel free to increase it if needed.

Comment: Still don't understand how did you figure out that it needs to be -300dp specifically

Comment: @uberchilly 300dp is arbitrary. if you have a specific height for your vertical divider, you should set at least (-height/2) padding on left and right, so there is enough space to draw the view after rotation.

Answer (score 46):

I think I've found a "cleaner" solution for this problem by creating a custom view containing specific code to draw the dashed lines (in both vertical and horizontal orientations), and a bunch of attributes to make it very easy to use it from XML layouts. The main advantage of this approach over the "rotated line" method is that you can set the size of the dashed line view the way you would normally do, without having to worry about how the view is going to behave after the rotation (once the rotation applies to the entire dashed line view and not only to the line being drawn).

So here is the step by step solution:

1. Create the file "/res/values/attrs.xml" with the following contents:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <resources>

   <declare-styleable name="DividerView">
       <attr name="color" format="color" />
       <attr name="dashLength" format="dimension" />
       <attr name="dashGap" format="dimension" />
       <attr name="dashThickness" format="dimension" />
       <attr name="orientation" format="enum">
           <enum name="horizontal" value="0" />
           <enum name="vertical" value="1" />
       </attr>
   </declare-styleable>

   </resources>
   ```

This creates the attributes to control the custom view.
Note: If the file above already exists in your project, just copy/paste the "declare-stylable" block inside the existing "resources" block.

2. Create the class DividerView and paste the contents below:

   ```
   public class DividerView extends View {
   static public int ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL = 0;
   static public int ORIENTATION_VERTICAL = 1;
   private Paint mPaint;
   private int orientation;

   public DividerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
       super(context, attrs);
       int dashGap, dashLength, dashThickness;
       int color;

       TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.DividerView, 0, 0);

       try {
           dashGap = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.DividerView_dashGap, 5);
           dashLength = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.DividerView_dashLength, 5);
           dashThickness = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.DividerView_dashThickness, 3);
           color = a.getColor(R.styleable.DividerView_color, 0xff000000);
           orientation = a.getInt(R.styleable.DividerView_orientation, ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL);
       } finally {
           a.recycle();
       }

       mPaint = new Paint();
       mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
       mPaint.setColor(color);
       mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
       mPaint.setStrokeWidth(dashThickness);
       mPaint.setPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[] { dashLength, dashGap, }, 0));
   }

   public DividerView(Context context) {
       this(context, null);
   }

   @Override
   protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
       if (orientation == ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL) {
           float center = getHeight() * .5f; 
           canvas.drawLine(0, center, getWidth(), center, mPaint);
       } else {
           float center = getWidth() * .5f; 
           canvas.drawLine(center, 0, center, getHeight(), mPaint);
       }
   }
   }
   ```
3. In order to use auto-complete of attributes on your layout files, add the following name
   space definition on the topmost container:

   ```
   xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example"
   ```

Replace `com.example` by the name of your package. You can also change `custom` by any prefix that better suits your needs.
Note: You may need to restart Eclipse to get the auto-complete working after changes on attrs.xml file.

4. And finally create your dashed lines by inserting the following
   element on your layout, like any other view:

   ```
   <com.example.DividerView
       android:layout_width="1dp"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:layerType="software" 
       custom:color="@color/grey"
       custom:orientation="vertical"
       custom:dashLength="1dp"
       custom:dashGap="1dp"
       custom:dashThickness="1dp" />
   ```

I hope it helps!

Comment: I just want to add that in the onDraw method the call drawLine did not work for me! Instead, I used canvas.drawPaint(mPaint);
It seems, that I am not the only one experiencing this issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=29944

Comment: You don't need to do step 3 now, you can just use "app:..." tags in xml

Comment: the best answer

Comment: Being new to Android, after reading this answer I got on the right track by reading - https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components . Lately I got used to read stackoverflow first documentation 2nd... This answers is a good short tutorial on how to write custom components. My advice would be to replace drawLine with drawPath so you can use Hardware rendering. Thx

Comment: Thanks.. You save my time

Comment: This answer is more like one! Because of exact line drawing without any padding.

Answer (score 27):

[image]

To achieve this, You should create 2 different drawable,

**1. Horizontal Line:** `res/drawable/bg_horizontal_dotted_line.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shape="line">
  <stroke
    android:width="0.8dp"
    android:color="@color/text_grey"
    android:dashWidth="4dp"
    android:dashGap="3dp" />
</shape>
```

**2. Vertical Drawable:** `res/drawable/bg_dotted_line_vertical.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item
    android:left="-600dp"
    android:right="-600dp">
    <rotate
      android:drawable="@drawable/bg_horizontal_dotted_line"
      android:fromDegrees="90"
      android:visible="true" />
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

Now, All you need to do is apply the above vertical XML into the view,

```
<View
            android:id="@+id/imageView7"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_dotted_line_vertical"
            android:layerType="software"/>
```

**Complete Code:**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:id="@+id/ll_task_expanded"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="200dp"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      app:canExpand="false"
      app:expanded="true">


      <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_circle" />

      <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView4"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_circle" />

      <View
        android:id="@+id/imageView7"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_dotted_line_vertical"
        android:layerType="software"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView6"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView5" />

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help @Nanda Gopal. The only concern is the hardcoded left and right position. I hope it works in every screen size.

Answer (score 16):

This works for me:

vertical_line.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
    <stroke
        android:width="1px"
        android:color="#60000000"
        android:dashGap="5px"
        android:dashWidth="5px" />
</shape>
```

In Layout:

```
<View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/vertical_line" />
```

Comment: this is a rectangle not a line

Answer (score 3):

I've tried so many things and the only thing that worked for me was this:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:left="-300dp"
        android:right="-300dp">
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="90"
            android:toDegrees="90">
            <shape android:shape="line" >
                <stroke
                    android:width="2dp"
                    android:dashGap="3dp"
                    android:dashWidth="3dp"
                    android:color="@color/disable" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: it worked, great work

Answer (score 2):

This one solves the problem nicely
Create drawable `line_dash.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:bottom="-1dp"
        android:left="-1dp"
        android:right="-1dp"
        android:top="0dp">

        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@color/grey_20"
                android:dashGap="3dp"
                android:dashWidth="3dp" />

            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

            <padding
                android:bottom="10dp"
                android:left="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:top="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Use it like this

```
 <View
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="1dp"
       android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing_middle"
       android:background="@drawable/line_dash" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<rotate
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromDegrees="90"
android:toDegrees="90"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%">
    <shape android:shape="line">
            <stroke
                android:width="20dp"
                android:color="@color/blue"
                android:dashWidth="20dp"
                android:dashGap="20dp" />
    </shape>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For the vertical line:

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="90"
    android:toDegrees="90">
    <shape
        android:shape="line">
        <stroke
            android:width="2dp"
            android:color="#ff00ff"
            android:dashWidth="8dp"
            android:dashGap="5dp" />
        <size android:width="120dp" />
    </shape>
</rotate>
```

For the horizontal line:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <shape
        android:shape="line">
        <stroke
            android:width="2dp"
            android:color="@color/accent_color"
            android:dashWidth="3dp"
            android:dashGap="2dp" />
    </shape>
</rotate>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:fromDegrees="90"
        android:toDegrees="90">
    <shape android:shape="line">
        <stroke
                android:color="@color/darkGray"
                android:width="1dp"
                android:dashGap="4dp"
                android:dashWidth="2dp"/>
    </shape>
</rotate>

<View
                android:layerType="software"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_vertical_dash_gray_1dp"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_15sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"/>
```

The key for the above code to get working is using `android:layerType="software"`.
For more information, check [this](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/reference/android/view/View.html#LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE) link.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below drawable code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="90"
            android:visible="true">
            <shape android:shape="line">
                <stroke
                    android:width="1dp"
                    android:color="@color/black"
                    android:dashWidth="8dp"
                    android:dashGap="3dp"
                    />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score -1):

This solution is 100% working and wish help you:

At first create a drawable which will draw a horizontal dashed line.

```
Let dashed line drawable name is horizontal_dashed_line.xml

  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="line">

     <stroke
      android:width="3dp"
      android:color="#80ffffff"
      android:dashWidth="20dp"
      android:dashGap="5dp" />
  </shape>
```

if you want to have vertical dashed line you have to rotate this drawable by followings:

```
Let drawable name is vertical_dashed_line.xml

  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="90"
    android:toDegrees="90"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:drawable="@drawable/horizontal_dashed_line">

  </rotate>
```

Now you have a horizontal and vertical dashed line.

How to use:

To draw horizontal line simply add horizontal_dashed_line.xml in your layout.
 For example:

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/horizontal_dashed_line"

    </RelativeLayout>
```

But if you want vertical line, just add vertical_dashed_line.xml instead of horizontal_dashed_line.xml.For example:

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/vertical_dashed_line"

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Good luck!