# How to develop a step number showing Viewpager Indicator in android?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I want to develop a step number ViewPager Indicator in android. When the user is on the first step the indicator will look like this.

[image: Initial Step]

And when he is on the last step, it should look like this.

[image: Last Step]

So, as I go forward in the ViewPager, I want the step numbers to go forward one step at a time showing the step number and lines connecting them highlighted.

**EDIT:**

The code of the layout of the indicator I have tried is as follows. I programmatically change the drawables of the images on page slide. But the problem is that how do I create the line connecting two steps and increment the progress on the page slide? Is there a library available?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_one"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/cb1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_two"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/cb2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_three"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/cb3"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_four"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/cb4"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_five"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/cb5"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_six"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/cb6"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: please improve your question by adding your layout and viewpager code

Comment: Unfortunately your question does not demonstrate any attempt of prior research. In order to get a good response, it is advised you should show evidence you have attempted to solve the problem, either in code or otherwise, before asking a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there're better ways to achieve what you want (better performance and memory efficiency, but much more complicated to achieve), but to follow with your current attempted solution you must:

to create the lines you'll include the following view between each ImageView (change the color, height and width as you need):

```
<View 
   android:layout_height="1px" 
   android:layout_width="8dp" 
   android:background="#f99">
```

and  to change status you'll call that on the ViewPager

```
pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener(){
   @Override public void onPageSelected(int position) {
      /// change status here
   }
});
```

Comment: Yeah I have done the same way now..
The thing is that I wanted to know if there was a library available for this thing just as ViewPagerIndicator.

Thanks for help.

Comment: do u mean this http://viewpagerindicator.com/ ? But this won't give the looks you want. Thinking a bit more about it, you could also use a XML drawable with a line shape and set it as the background of your `LinearLayout`, like those http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20583298/creating-horizontal-and-vertical-dotted-lines-in-android this would make your layout a bit lighter.

Comment: Yeah...Thanks for that link. I have drawn the line using shape drawable and connected 2 ImageView with it.

Answer (score 2):

IN Xml try this code ..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background_dark"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.layer_net.stepindicatorexample.MainActivity">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="10dp">
            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="18dp"
                            android:layout_height="18dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="left|center"
                            android:src="@drawable/dot_white" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="18dp"
                            android:layout_height="18dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:src="@drawable/dot_white" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="18dp"
                            android:layout_height="18dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="right|center"
                            android:src="@drawable/dot_white" />
                    </LinearLayout>


                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1">

                        <ProgressBar
                            android:id="@+id/bar"
                            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_margin="5dp"
                            android:indeterminate="false"
                            android:max="100"
                            android:maxHeight="5dip"
                            android:minHeight="5dip"
                            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/greenprogress" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1">

                        <ProgressBar
                            android:id="@+id/bar2"
                            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_margin="5dp"
                            android:indeterminate="false"
                            android:max="100"
                            android:maxHeight="5dip"
                            android:minHeight="5dip"
                            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/second_progress_bar" />
                    </LinearLayout>


                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"

                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="18dp"
                            android:layout_height="18dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="left|center"
                            android:padding="0.5dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/dot_orange" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/second_dot"
                            android:layout_width="18dp"
                            android:layout_height="18dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:padding="0.5dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/dot_white" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/third_dot"
                            android:layout_width="18dp"
                            android:layout_height="18dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="right|center"
                            android:padding="0.5dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/dot_white" />
                    </LinearLayout>


                </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>



        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

IN Activity  View Pager try this:-

```
 mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

                int round = Math.round(positionOffset * 100);

                Log.e("positionOffset", ">>" + position);
                int progress = round;
                if (position == 0) {
                    progressBar.setProgress(progress);
                    if(progressBar.getProgress()<95){
                        second_dot.setImageResource(R.drawable.dot_white);
                    }
                } else if(position==1) {
                    second_dot.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_dot);
                    bar2.setProgress(progress);
                    if(bar2.getProgress()<95){
                        third_dot.setImageResource(R.drawable.dot_white);
                    }

                }
                else if(position==2){
                  third_dot.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue_dot);
                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
 Drawable greenprogress.xml code :-
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/line_12" />
    <item android:id="@android:id/background"

        >
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#fff" />
            <stroke
                android:width="0.5px"
                android:color="#fff" />
            <corners android:radius="5dp" />


        </shape>
    </item>


    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <stroke
                    android:width="0.5px"
                    android:color="#fff" />
                <corners android:radius="5dp" />
                <gradient
                    android:endColor="#c3464e"
                    android:startColor="#ffa200" />
            </shape>
        </clip>

    </item>

</layer-list>
```

second_progress_bar.xml code :-

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:id="@+id/progress"
            android:drawable="@drawable/line_12"/>
        <item android:id="@android:id/background"

            >
            <shape >
                <solid android:color="#fff"/>
                <stroke android:width="0.5px"
                    android:color="#fff"
                    />
                <corners android:radius="5dp"/>


            </shape>
        </item>


        <item
            android:id="@android:id/progress"
            >
            <clip>
                <shape>
                    <stroke android:width="0.5px"
                        android:color="#fff"
                        />




                    <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
                    <gradient
                        android:startColor="#c3464e"
                        android:endColor="#38a0da"
                        />
                </shape>
            </clip>

        </item>

    </layer-list>
```

These are three smooth step sync with view pager.You can easily customize the code according to your need.

**Result**

[image: Step-2]

[image: Step-3]

[image: Step-1]

Thanks & Happy to help  :)